# How to open offcanva menu from the site

Tags: html, css, menu

I using a mobile menu for my website which is dropping down from the top to the bottom. Is their a way to get it open from the left, like the sidebar does? I'm not that familiar with `css` animation and I tried `transform: rotate(90deg);` but without any effects.

The mobile menu is visible here https://www.amaoni.de

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We are also not going to dig through your source code. Please add a relevant code snippet. We can't see what is wrong without the snippet. Also if your site would change or go offline the question wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

it can be easily done by using `ul`,`li` tags

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }
  
  #yourMenu{
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:200px;
    width:30%;
   }
   #yourMenu>li{
     width:100%;
     padding:5px;
     background-color:blue;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     color:#fff;
    }
    #yourMenu>li:hover{
     cursor:pointer;
     background-color:red;
   
    }
```

```html
<ul id="yourMenu">
  <li>menu 1</li>
  <li>menu 2</li>
  <li>menu 3</li>
</ul>
```